# Best Practice: Angular SSR Partial Pre-rendering with dynamic fallback

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal, prerender

**Background:** Using Angular Universal to perform pre-rendering but not all routes will be rendered (query parametered or authenticated-only pages for the most part), so wanting to fallback to the express renderer as needed.

**Quick Replication (bash):**

```html
npm install -g @angular/cli@next
ng new partial-prerender -s -t --minimal --routing --interactive=false
cd partial-prerender/
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@'^9.0.0-rc.1'
ng g m child --route child --module app
cat << 'EOF' > src/app/app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `<div [routerLink]="['/']">Root</div><div [routerLink]="['child']">Child</div><router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class AppComponent {}
EOF
npm run prerender
npm run serve:ssr
```

This quick replication will produce the app, universal implementation, a child page, and replace the app html to give 2 links and a router outlet, then build/pre-render. Both routes will be pre-rendered, but this is good enough for discussing the issue.

**Problem:** Dynamic SSR is performed as the Express server will pick up the request rather than serving the pre-rendered static file. URLs are normally accessed without the `/index.html` specified.

Note the static files can be found at `/dist/partial-prerender/browser/index.html` and `.../child/index.html`. For testing, I've replaced the contents of these files with garbage, just to be sure which is being loaded at a glance.

Can also add a `console.log('DYNAMIC');` to the `server.ts`:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('DYNAMIC');
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
});
```

When making a request to `localhost:4000` or `localhost:4000/child`, the 'DYNAMIC' will be printed and the dynamically rendered version is produced, not giving me my mangled pre-rendered files.

When making a request to `localhost:4000/index.html` or `localhost:4000/child/index.html`, the

```
server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, { maxAge: '1y' }));
```

picks up and serves the mangled files.

All makes sense and why it's happening, but I want to be able to just hit a given url (without the `/index.html` and receive the pre-rendered files (when available), then fall back to putting SSR to work.

---

**Potential Solution:**
Modify `server.ts` to test for file existence matching the given request path + `/index.html` and serve them, falling back to the `res.render(...`

- Is this the best way?

  - If so, why wouldn't this be default functionality? My only guess is flexibility of you doing this with your reverse proxy while not adding this overhead of checking.
- What's the best way to do so?

  - Haven't used Express heavily in maybe 6 years, but feel like `express.static` should be utilized in some way over `fs`
  - If `fs` is the answer, would it make sense to cache the pre-rendered files in memory?

If it helps, I produce an alpine-node container and deploy to K8s with an Nginx ingress. Only mention this as maybe there's a magical `try-files`-like functionality that can be done to 'attempt' a file + `/index.html` retrieval from the node container, then fallback without the `/index.html`, but seems highly unlikely.

Comment: If you using nginx or any other webserver as a reverse proxy, you could get that webserver to check if the corresponding pre-rendered file exists; it if it does, serve it; if it does not, fall back on angular universal  dynamic SSR

Comment: @David Have nginx as an ingress on K8s, which directs traffic to the pod, so it can't do `try-files` directly as it's not within the container. The closest I could do is run a container with both nginx and node that hosts the app. Think it's worth the overhead rather than node/express just doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd say to let nodejs handle it for simplicity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an if statement inside the get request like this

```
const fullPath = join(distFolder, req.originalUrl);
  if (existsSync(fullPath)) {
    console.log('STATIC Exists');
    return res.sendFile(join(distFolder, req.originalUrl));
  } else {
     //Dynamic
     res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install @nguniversal/express-engine@11.2.1 --save
```

It already brings the static page by default.

Comment: Nope -- just attempted again from a fresh install (`npx ng version` - Angular CLI: 11.2.8 + @nguniversal/express-engine: 11.2.1). Created a child page (`ng g m child --route child --module app`), added a log in `server:ts::34` to log the URL calling to the renderer, then ran `npm run build:ssr && npm run prerender && npm run serve:ssr`. `/`, `/child`, then back to `/` all call the render endpoint.